# Cannot connect database and throwing error

Tags: firebird2.5

I am a linux user. I did installed Firebird, following below url helps.

http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg10-creating.html#d0e1325

When I try to connect database the below error message is shown.

**command**  isql-fb '/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb' -u firebird -p 'admin'

Statement failed, SQLSTATE = -902
Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Firebird from rpms? I had the same issue that you describe when trying to create a db, on fedora. I managed to resolve it by removing the rpms and installing them again with yum.

Also make sure that your data path exists and has the correct permissions. Mine is `/var/lib/firebird/data/` and I can create a database with this command from isql-fb console (using default admin credentials).

`SQL> create database "/var/lib/firebird/data/test.fdb" user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';`

Answer (score 0):

open /opt/firebird/bin/gsec
and try this:
GSEC> modify sysdba -pw masterkey 
and quit

it works!